# "Object lock not owned" error while using OnPaint method

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to draw a simple image with OnPaint method. The code compiles just fine, but when the application starts, it shows "Object lock not owned" error and nothing else happens. Could you please tell me what mistake I made? The code shows the OnPaint event I'm using. Thank you all for your help.

```
procedure TTabbedForm.Image1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
  var
  p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6: TPointF;
  prst1: TRectF;
  i :Integer;
begin
 Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
 Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 3;
 p1 := TPointF.Create(PX, PY);
 Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  with TabbedForm do begin
      for i := 0 to 360 do
        if (i mod 15)=0 then
        begin
         p2 := TPointF.Create(Round(PX+PP*sin(i*pi/180)), Round(PY+PP*cos(i*pi/180)));
          Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);
        end;
      for i := 0 to PP do
        if (i mod 20)=0 then
        begin
        prst1 := TRectF.Create(PX+i,PY+i,PX-i,PY-i);
        Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse(prst1, 100);
        end;
      for i := 0 to 400 do
        if (i mod 20)=0 then
        begin
        p3 := TPointF.Create(i,2*PP);
        p4 := TPointF.Create(i,2*PP+2*PP);
        Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p3, p4, 100);
        end;
      for i := 0 to 400 do
        if (i mod 20)=0 then
        begin
        p5 := TPointF.Create(0,2*PP+i);
        p6 := TPointF.Create(2*PP+2*PP,2*PP+i);
        Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p5, p6, 100);
        end;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
 end;
```

Comment: Do you know the exception is in this code? Did the debugger stop there (which line)? Do you still get the error when you comment out this code? I would associate that error with multithreading, TTask, mutexes maybe, but not with painting...

Comment: I'm not that familiar yet with FMX graphic, but I think you may want to read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.BeginScene . It has some interesting remarks, including *"Notice that calling BeginScene in the OnPaint event handlers has no effect."*. Also the fact that BeginScene returns a boolean, and you should only draw when it returns true (and only call EndScene in that case!)... I think that last one might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: In addition, TImage is for displaying pre-generated or pre-loaded bitmaps. For direct drawing on a control, TPaintBox is the better option. I think altering the bitmap of an image inside it's paint handler could have all kinds of negative side effects. See [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Objects.TPaintBox) *"Unlike TImage, which displays a picture that is stored in a file, TPaintBox requires an application to draw the image directly on a canvas. Use the OnPaint event handler to draw on the paint box's FMX.Graphics.TCanvas, the drawing surface of the paint box."*

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. Please provide a [mcve]. Reduce your code to the minimal that still leads to the error.

Comment: I have voted to close this q as you have failed to provide the MCVE requested by @TomBrunberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "Object lock not owned" is the message of `EMonitorLockException`, which is documented to be raised "whenever a thread tries to release the lock on a non-owned monitor". Since you have not responded to my request for an MCVE, and I have not been able to reproduce this error, I can not confirm whether it is due to an unsuccessful lock aquisition through `Canvas.BeginScene`, or something else.

You can use either a `TImage` or a `TPaintBox` for your drawing. Using a `TImage` provides many benefits such as directly loading an image file, drawing on that image and saving your image to a file directly in various formats, like `.bmp`, `.jpg` or `.png` (maybe others too). A `TPaintBox` is more lightweight and doesnt have an own bitmap, but uses the parent components surface to draw on (therefore the need for an `OnPaint()` handler). Loading from / saving to file must be done e.g. through a separate TBitmap.

So yes, you may continue to use a TImage control if you want, but in that case, do not use the `OnPaint` event for the drawing as you are now. A TImage has a built in mechanism to paint itself when needed. You only need to draw your drawing once to the built-in bitmap canvas. In the following code the image is drawn in a `ButtonClick()` event. Also note, that with the TImage you must use `BeginScene` - `EndScene` correctly as documented.

You must also set the `TImage.Bitmap.Size` before drawing on it. If this was not set elsewhere in your code of what you have shown, then that may be another reason why your code produced no image.

Draw your image on `Image1.Bitmap.Canvas` e.g. in a `OnClick()` event of a button:

```
procedure TTabbedForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6: TPointF;
  prst1: TRectF;
  i: integer;
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.SetSize(300, 300); // must be set before call to BeginScene
  if Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1;
    p1 := TPointF.Create(px, py);

    for i := 0 to 360 do
      if (i mod 15) = 0 then
      begin
        pp := i;
        p2 := TPointF.Create(Round(px + pp * sin(i * pi / 180)),
          Round(py + pp * cos(i * pi / 180)));
        Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);
      end;

    for i := 0 to pp do
    ...

    for i := 0 to 400 do
    ...

    for i := 0 to 400 do
    ....

  finally
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get this error message, because you're drawing on the canvas at a time  when you're not allowed to. Potential causes for this are:

- You're drawing on the bitmap of the image from the paint event of the image. Images are for displaying pre-generated or loaded bitmaps, and since modifying the bitmap should trigger the OnPaint event, I think it's a bad idea to make those changes from that same event. It's asking for an endless loop, or other unwanted side effects.
- You're using BeginScene/EndScene incorrectly. You should only proceed drawing if BeginScene returns true. And actually it's not needed to call them at all when drawing on the given canvas of a paint event.
- You're (partially) using a global instance of the form instead of the current instance (Self), which could (depending on your application), lead to drawing on the wrong instance.

Small disclaimer: I left your code as-is as much as possible, just changed the things that I think could potentially cause your problem. I think these changes all make sense, but I must admit I've never done much painting in FMX, so maybe some of these are a bit naive or over-protective (or blatantly wrong).

Things that are different in this code compared to yours:

- Use a TPaintbox (you'll have to add a TPaintbox named 'Paintbox1', and add this method to it's OnPaint handler). Paintboxes are for direct drawing. You could also keep the image, if you would be able to pre-render the image's bitmap on specific events, like the start of your application, a click of a button, a timer, and so on.
- <strike>Correct use of BeginScene and EndScene, with an `if` and a `try..finally` block. BeginScene will give you a lock or not, and return a boolean depending on the success. You should only proceed if you actually acquired the lock, and only call EndScene in that case too, because they are ref counted, and doing this wrong could screw up the refcount, and therefor all further painting in your application.</strike>
- <strike>Stroke settings inside the scene as well. Not 100% sure if needed, but I guess it's part of drawing the scene too, right?</strike>
- Left out `BeginScene..EndScene` completely. The Paintbox or Image control should already have called that itself. See [FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.BeginScene docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.BeginScene)
- Just use `Canvas`. It's passed as a parameter to the event handler, so better to use that, then to try and find the right canvas yourself.
- Removed the `with`. This is a bit of a long shot, but it looked like you were referring to a global `TTabbedForm` variable, and since you are inside a TTabbedForm method, you should be able to use the properties and methods of the current instance as-is, or prepend with `Self.` if you run into naming conflicts. It's always better to not rely on those globals for forms and datamodules, and you'll actually run into problems if you want to have multiple instances of your form, in which case your original code would *partially* operate on the wrong instance.

```pascal
procedure TTabbedForm.Paintbox1Paint(
  Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var
  p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6: TPointF;
  prst1: TRectF;
  i :Integer;
begin
  p1 := TPointF.Create(PX, PY);
  Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
  Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 3;

  for i := 0 to 360 do
    if (i mod 15)=0 then
    begin
      p2 := TPointF.Create(Round(PX+PP*sin(i*pi/180)), Round(PY+PP*cos(i*pi/180)));
      Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);
    end;
  for i := 0 to PP do
    if (i mod 20)=0 then
    begin
      prst1 := TRectF.Create(PX+i,PY+i,PX-i,PY-i);
      Canvas.DrawEllipse(prst1, 100);
    end;
  for i := 0 to 400 do
    if (i mod 20)=0 then
    begin
      p3 := TPointF.Create(i,2*PP);
      p4 := TPointF.Create(i,2*PP+2*PP);
      Canvas.DrawLine(p3, p4, 100);
    end;
  for i := 0 to 400 do
    if (i mod 20)=0 then
    begin
      p5 := TPointF.Create(0,2*PP+i);
      p6 := TPointF.Create(2*PP+2*PP,2*PP+i);
      Canvas.DrawLine(p5, p6, 100);
    end;
end;
```